# Rails video embedding gem, service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube, vimeo

Hi there i've had a look around for some video embedding tools i can use for my site, i'm looking at letting user embed video into a site through their profile, i've got the images down with paperclip, i was lo
oking at embedly looked good but the implementation of it looked a little complex for me, any suggestions would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used http://sproutvideo.com/ in the past.  Worked as expected, although it's not free.  Couldn't use a free service without breaking agreements and such for that project.

Comment: actually, i checked it out, but ah, its notpart of their core platform.